# Changing background of body on every new slide of a jquery slider

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a div 800px * 800px. Within this DIV I have some jquery slider having dimensions say 400px * 400px. Now the slider contains few images such as image1,image2,image3 etc. What I want is that when the slide changes in the slider, the background of 800px*800px must also change. For example if the slider is showing image1, then the background of bigger div must also be image1 and so on change synchronously. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your slider has the same number of steps as the number of images, then you could do use the ["slide" event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs) of the slider to synchronise the two divs.

e.g.

```
// variables for the divs mentioned
var $div800 = $('#div800'); // or whatever
var $div400 = $('#div400'); // or whatever
// after creating the slider...
$('slider selector here').bind('slide', function(event, ui) {
    var url = 'http://example.com/images/image' + ui.value + '.jpg'; // or however you construct your url to the image
    $div800.css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
 });
```